# How to use Froala editor as inline option in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, froala

I have installed Froala editor in Ionic. It is working properly. In my `**home.html**` I have added this line of code

```
<div [froalaEditor]>Hello, Froala!</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

How can I use it inline in Ionic?

Their documentations guides for js but I don't know how to get the same implemented in Ionic, below is their instruction

**HTML**

```
<div id="froala-editor1">
  <p>This is the first editor instance</p>
  <img src="/assets/editor/docs/photo14.jpg" class="fr-fil" alt="book" width="150"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>

  $(function() {
    $('div#froala-editor1').froalaEditor({
      toolbarInline: true,
      toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'color', 'emoticons', '-', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'indent', 'outdent', '-', 'insertImage', 'insertLink', 'insertFile', 'insertVideo', 'undo', 'redo']
    })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ionic implementation is using Angular. See https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg#usage. You should basically do something like this in your component and then pass the options to the directive.

```
public options: Object = {
  toolbarInline: true,
  toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'color', 'emoticons', '-', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'indent', 'outdent', '-', 'insertImage', 'insertLink', 'insertFile', 'insertVideo', 'undo', 'redo']
}



<div [froalaEditor]='options'>Hello, Froala!</div>
```

Comment: i have integrated it, but there is a problem, when i press enter and type something, the text and its html values are not getting fetched when i am trying to fetch the value of div using `this.TAG = $('#froala-editor_child').html()`  What can be the issue ?

Comment: i have also posted a seperate question which you can find here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389762/froala-editor-no-data-is-getting-fetch-except-data-on-first-line